# Какими должны быть выходные значения выходного нейрона

Tags: машинное-обучение

Прошу прощения за тавтологию, собственно вопрос в заголовке. Знаю что скрытые нейроны оперируют данными в диапазоне от `0` до `1`, а данные с входов входных нейронов проходят нормализацию т.е. как раз приведение любого значения к интервалу от `0` до `1`, но как быть с выходными нейронами ? Что если на выходе мне нужно получить не от `0` до `1` а от `-22` до `33` (например `11`) - предусмотрена ли для этих целей процедура обратная нормализации или для этого нужно больше выходных нейронов, по принципу :

`О1` - нейрон показывает что ответ более 5 (да  =  1)

`О2` - нейрон показывает что ответ более 10, (да = 1)

`О3` - нейрон показывает что ответ менее 12,  (да = 1)

И таким образом все три `1-1-1` дают нам повод считать что результатом будет 11, так ли? Это только мои догадки, тк исчерпывающей литературы в инете не нашел. Если не сложно, дайте пару ссылок на англоязычные ресурсы по теме. Спасибо.

UPD Изначально хотел написать сеть, которая бы предсказывала поведение графика вот такой сложной функции :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Однако вариантов значения OY уже 3 => -1 или 0 или 1.  А если их будет от -1 до 10 с шагом 0.1 - совсем не понятно как построить вывод таких данных.

Comment: какого рода у вас сеть? и что предсказываете - классификация, регрессия?

Comment: @MaxU изначально, планировал сеть предсказывающую продолжение графика вот такой сложной функции :: `https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2018/1/29/90285783e662f28f45f0fa1bfc0dff02-full.png`

Comment: @MaxU но поскольку каждая следующая точка может быть равна -1 или 0 или 1 (а может еще гораздо больше) то факт того что нейроны работают только с интервалом от 0 до 1 немного сбил с толку.

Comment: Картинка не доступна

Comment: @MaxU обновил вопрос

Comment: Не очень понятно на основании каких данных вы хотите предсказывать функцию. Только значение по оси X? Тогда вам лучше всего подойдет какое-нибудь разложение в ряд фурье без всяких новомодных нейронных сетей. А вообще то что вы пытаетесь сделать называется задачей регрессии, впринципе её можно решать с помощью нейронных сетей, нужно только на последнем слое делать какую-нибудь обычную линейную регрессию и желательно добавить на вход каких-нибудь предрасчитанных фич, в вашем случае хорошо подойдут фичи типа sin(alpha*x), где разные alpha можно с помощью преобразования фурье поискать :)

Comment: Визуальный пример как работает задача регрессии: http://playground.tensorflow.org/#activation=sigmoid&batchSize=10&dataset=circle&regDataset=reg-gauss&learningRate=0.03&regularizationRate=0&noise=0&networkShape=4,2&seed=0.15697&showTestData=false&discretize=false&percTrainData=50&x=true&y=true&xTimesY=false&xSquared=false&ySquared=false&cosX=false&sinX=false&cosY=false&sinY=false&collectStats=false&problem=regression&initZero=false&hideText=false

По ссылке задача предсказания значения функции от двух переменных (Х и Y). Цвет точки - значение функции по этим координатам. Надо нажать на play

Answer (score 1):

Чтоб лучше (четче) распознавать что на выходе, выходное значение следует рассматривать просто как "да"  или "нет", без промежуточных значений типа 0.5 (это будет значить что сеть не в курсе как распознать). 
Если ты хочешь именно **предсказывать** значения сложной функции, то есть у тебя RNN/LSTN что ли, делаешь выход 55 значений, от 0 до 1, первое - самое низкое (-22), второе - самое высокое (33), во время треннировки подаёшь флаги где все нули и только одно значение единица.
Или ты можешь попробовать как ты сказал.
Всегда можно чё то пробовать, эта область ещё развивается)
Выходом у тебя будет одно значение , с линейным маппингом от 0 (-22) до 1 (33), без функции активации, ошибку считаешь просто полученное - ожидаемое.
Попробуешь оба варианта отпишешься что лучше работает. 
Работать будет всё, так как минимизировать можно что хочешь, вот только насколько хорошо, быстро обучаемо и т.п. :DD

Comment: это может сработать если заранее известен интервал в котором находится ответ.

Comment: тиебе не надо знать интервал.